# How to Hide or Show Axis Labels programmatically in Core Plot?

Tags: label, core-plot

I plan to add touch event features including an annotation on X axis with Core Plot. the problem is that the annotation on the axis can hide axis labels.

Is it possible to hide the axis labels during the touch down or drag event, and show them back upon touch up event. Some properties or methods, maybe?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to hide them, you can loop through the `axisLabels` set and hide or show the `contentLayer` of each label with the `hidden` property.

You can also remove the labels to hide them. For custom labels (`CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone`), just set the `axisLabels` to `nil` to hide them and assign new labels to show them again. For other labeling policies, set the `labelTextStyle` and/or `labelFormatter` to `nil` to hide the labels and restore them to show the labels again.

Comment: Thanks Eric. It works. The workaround I did, is changing the label color to match the background.